# How do I get back my latitude / longitude after coercion

Tags: postgis

I'm using PostGIS. When I enter the following, you can see that the input point is transformed:

```sql
=# SELECT ST_ASEWKT(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-33.7832527413259  151.120353207011)'));                                          
NOTICE:  Coordinate values were coerced into range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY
                     st_asewkt                      
----------------------------------------------------
 SRID=4326;POINT(-33.7832527413259 28.879646792989)
(1 row)
```

Firstly I don't understand why the point is transformed (it's for a point in Sydney Australia so it's a real lat/lon) nor can I work out how to get the original lon value back (~123 is an odd size difference)

Any suggestions (probably a bit of a noob question as this is my first use of a GIS system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your coordinates in the input point are backwards, try

```sql
SELECT ST_ASEWKT(ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(151.120353207011 -33.7832527413259)'));
```

Comment: Now you say that I realise you are correct, thanks.